# An example of the use of a `friend` specifier in a destructor?

Tags: c++, language-lawyer, destructor, friend

[[class.dtor]/1](http://eel.is/c++draft/class.dtor#1) contains the following sentence:

> Each *decl-specifier* of the *decl-specifier-seq* of a destructor
>   declaration (if any) shall be `friend`, `inline`, or `virtual`.

I'm really interested in seeing an example of the use of a destructor with a `friend` specifier.

Comment: Isn't that so you can befriend the destructor of another class?

Comment: By [Meta vote](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/365722/questions-looking-for-an-example), this shall stand.

Answer (score 11):

Suppose you want to allow private members of class `A` to be used in class `B`. No problem, you declare `B` as a friend inside `A`.

Suppose further that you want to restrict the usage to `B`'s destructor only. Thus, you only declare `B`'s destructor as a friend:

```
struct A
{
private:
    // some private stuff
    friend B::~B();
};
```

See [this example on ideone](https://ideone.com/GgaRty).

Comment: Apparently you can declare an implicitly declared function a friend, too: [Like this.](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/ecd5350d985b3a5f)

Comment: But you don't need this. See the counterexample [here](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/ffd40896fbe8cb0e).

Comment: @Alexander True, but you don't even *need* to make anything private - all this are just different design decisions.

Comment: Your "counterexample" `B::~B()` doesn't use anything private from `A`.

Comment: @molbdnilo I don't need to use any private member of `A` to do what the OP's code does. That's why I called it a counterexample.

Answer (score 4):

Basically, if you declare a destructor of say class `A` inside the class definition of class `B` as `friend`, `A::~A` may be able to access private elements of `B`. The same applies for any member function of `A`. This can be useful if you want to only allow specific functions of `A` to be able to access `B`'s private members instead of declaring it a full `friend class`.

```
class B;

struct A {
   A() : b{ new B } { }
   B* b;
   ~A();
};

class B {
   friend A::~A();
   void member() { } 
};

A::~A() {
   b->member(); // possible as ~A is friend
   delete b;
}
```

Comment: @Leon Because a trivial main function is missing that would add nothing relevant to the example. The intention of this answer was to give an usecase, not to deliver a program with unnecessary details.